# Static routing using 2 routers and 1 multi-layered switch

Tags: cisco, routing

I'm trying to configure a static route between two routers and a layer 3 switch as follows -

[image]

**Router 0**

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.17.10.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 172.16.10.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 172.16.11.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.10.2 
!
ip flow-export version 9
```

**L3 Switch**

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no switchport
 ip address 172.17.10.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 no switchport
 ip address 172.17.10.5 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip classless
ip route 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.10.1 
ip route 172.16.11.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.10.6 
!
ip flow-export version 9
```

**Router 1**

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.17.10.6 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 172.16.11.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 172.16.11.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.10.5 
ip route 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.10.5 
!
ip flow-export version 9
```

The switch can ping all devices but the Routers can't ping each other. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: sadly school assignments are off-topic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Router 0 knows nothing about the networks beyond the layer-3 switch and needs specific routes, so you could put in static routes for each network beyond the layer-3 switch that point to the layer-3 switch.

The layer-3 switch needs more specific routes to the networks on the other side of the routers pointing to the routers.

Router 1 needs more specific routes to the networks on the other side of the layer-3 switch.

---

**Edit:**

Router 0:

```
ip route 172.17.10.4 255.255.255.252 172.17.10.2
ip route 172.16.11.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.10.2
```

Layer-3 Switch

```
ip route 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.10.1
ip route 172.16.11.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.10.6
```

Router 1

```
ip route 172.17.10.0 255.255.255.252 172.17.10.5
ip route 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.10.5
```

Comment: I got through this by adding default routes - `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <interface>`. What I don't understand is why it wouldn't work when I added the next hop (which is not the same device) instead of the interface (which is the same device). And If I hadn't used the default routes, what would be the complete static routes for this?

Answer (score 0):

Router0 interface is directly connected with layer3 switch interface . So it is possible to ping from router0 to layer3 switch .

But we are unable to ping Router0 to Router1 interface is because it's not directly and to ensure connectivity . With Specific router interface ip address static routes required to configure on all three devices .

Because of below mentioned  route entries configured in Router1 .PC on either network  are unable to ping from . To ensure connectivity delete this route entry from router1 and further check connectivity from PC1 to PC2 also of either networks

**ip route 172.16.11.0 255.255.255.0 172.17.10.5**